# Is it safe to make a contract call from a giant loop?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, callcode, user-safety, solidity-0.8.x

I have this function in solidity:

```
function payPlayers(address[] memory players, uint256[] memory values) public payable returns (bool[] memory result) {
        result = new bool[](players.length);
        for (uint i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            result[i] = false;
            (bool success, ) = players[i].call{value: values[i]}("");
            if (success) {
                result[i] = true;
            }            
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I was reading about many calls made in giant loops that can cause block overflow and some transaction will fail. Is this correct?

What size of the players array can be safest for this loop so that all calls will work?
Thanks in advance.